# How to use variable from a method from another file?

Tags: python

I made a Snake game with the help of Angela Wu's 100 days of Coding Python course on Udemy. Every time the "food" gets eaten, the snake gets longer. So far so good.
I changed the color of the new food to a random color using the function `make_color` in `food.py`:

```
    def make_color(self):
        r = random.randint(0, 255)
        g = random.randint(0, 255)
        b = random.randint(0, 255)
        random_color = r, g, b
        return random_color
```

In the following method, where the new snake segment gets created, I called this method:

```
    def refresh(self):
        self.setheading(random.randint(0, 360))
        self.color(self.make_color())
        random_x = random.randint(-280, 280)
        random_y = random.randint(-280, 280)
        self.goto(random_x, random_y)
```

Both are inside the Food class.

So now every new food has a random color, as desired.

When the food gets eaten, the snake gains another segment; this is handled in `snake.py` inside the Snake class:

```
    def add_segment(self, position):
        new_segment = Turtle(shape="square")
        new_segment.color(255, 255, 255)
        new_segment.penup()
        new_segment.goto(position)
        self.segments.append(new_segment)
```

This works totally fine, the new segment is white since I used `255, 255, 255`. But I want it to have the **same** random color as the food it just ate. And I just can't get it to work.

I guess I need to use the `random_color` variable from `food.py` but I can't figure out how. `food` is imported in the snake.py via `from food import Food`

Comment: Nice job showing just the relevant code! And good that you're asking questions above and beyond the tutorial.

Comment: You should be proud of yourself. Many of us have seen a lot of beginner programers post low quality questions (which is to be expected). This is, bar none, the best question posed by a beginner programmer I have seen. You're gonna go far, kid.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the `add_segment` method to take another argument along with `position`, in this case that argument should be a `Food` object (so maybe call the argument `food`). Then, within `add_segment` you can extract the colour of the `food` (assuming the `color` method in `Food` sets an attribute containing the colour tuple, or there's a method called, say, `get_color()` that gets the tuple). E.g.:

```py
def add_segment(self, position, food):
    new_segment = Turtle(shape="square")
    new_segment.color(food.get_colour())
    new_segment.penup()
    new_segment.goto(position)
    self.segments.append(new_segment)
```

This does mean you'll need to change wherever in your code `add_segment` is called to pass it the food object that has just been consumed.

Comment: If op wants the same color as a specific food, this is the right answer. Mine is more philosophical

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for alle the help and comments! Ill try to continue just showing relevant code.

In the end I found a different way to solve my problem:

I added an empty list to the top of the file
`color_list = []`.
In the make_color method I used list.append() to add the random_color to the list:

```
def make_color(self):
        r = random.randint(0, 255)
        g = random.randint(0, 255)
        b = random.randint(0, 255)
        random_color = r, g, b
        color_list.append(random_color)
```

Where the new snake segment gets created, I changed it to this:

```
    def add_segment(self, position):
        new_segment = Turtle(shape="square")
        new_segment.color(color_list[0])
        new_segment.penup()
        new_segment.goto(position)
        self.segments.append(new_segment)
```

So now it takes the first color from the color list and uses it for the snake segment. First, I used [-1] so it always used the last one that has been added. But with that, the list gets longer and longer.
So before the new food gets created, I added `color_list.clear()`. Now the list only consists of the current color that gets created for the food, used for the snake segment when the snake ate the food and then gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in `make_color`, you don't use the argument `self`. That's a good rule of thumb that something shouldn't be in your class, since it's a utility function. And as you've found, utility functions are useful everywhere, not just the first place you wrote them.

The first step is to take `make_color` outside the class and remove the `self` argument:

```
def make_color():
    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    random_color = r, g, b
    return random_color
```

Now in `snake.py`, you import it along with `Food`:

```
from food import Food, make_color
```

And voila, you can use it anywhere in the `snake` module now. Don't forget to splat the arguments:

```
new_segment.color(*make_color())
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what OP was asking. The objective is to make the new_segment the same color as the food the snake just ate. Wouldn't this make the color a new random color?

Comment: Note: saw your comment in Matt's answer. While this doesn't answer OP's direct question, I think it's useful for demonstrative purposes as the objective, really, is to learn coding principles, not make a snake game.